# Button style on chrome differs from the rest

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I want to style a "sign in with facebook" button using the facebook icon in font-awesome and bootstrap

for this I have the following html

```
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-large login_facebook">
<i class="icon-facebook"> </i> | Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

and adding to this the proper css

```
.login_facebook {
    background: #6e86bd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6e86bd 0%, #6680b9 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#6e86bd), to(#6680b9));
    border-top: 1px solid #3f5b98;
    border-left: 1px solid #3f5b98;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3f5b98;
    border-right: 1px solid #3f5b98;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #abbbdf;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #abbbdf;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #abbbdf;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #344d80;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
.login_facebook .icon-facebook {
    font-size: 37px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

on chrome the f icon is aligned with the bottom of the button but on firefox, ie it doesn't

the end result should be looking like this on all browsers

[image]

best seen on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KM2tS/1/

I am guessing I need to add browser specific styles here, but which styles? and is there a way to make all browsers behave the same in this specfic case?

Comment: Give it a set height of like `height: 30px` then to make sure the height stays the same. That's a lot of code for a button you don't need that many lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() 
{
    .icon-facebook:before
    {
        height: 5px !important;
    }

}
```

Add the above style and try.

Comment: Could you please add a screen shot of your requirement and how it appears now.

Comment: sure, added it to the question

Comment: I have changed the code, so that it will affect only FF and will not make any change in Chrome.

Comment: .icon-facebook:before
    {
        height: 5px !important;
    } working for IE ?